# String.format() and DecimalFormat not actually formatting

Tags: android, number-formatting, string.format, decimalformat

I've tried two different ways of formatting some numbers to show up similar to money, so to 2 decimal places.
However, I have tried setting the EditText field to

`EditText.setText (String.format("%.2f, number))`

as well as:

```
DecimalFormat precision = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
EditText.setText(String.valueOf(precision.format(number));
```

and neither has seemed to do anything, everything still defaults as setting to a 1 decimal place, ie) 30.0, and if its anything else it will go to 3 or more decimal places ie) 30.243

Comment: not getting your question and what you want.??

Comment: I think your code is correct, please check it careful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Mason Richardson

Have you tried `setMinimumFractionDigits()` which sets minimum fractions for your value

```
 DecimalFormat precision = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
 dec.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
 EditText.setText(String.valueOf(precision.format(number));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
DecimalFormat precision = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
edittext.setText(precision.format(number));
```

Answer (score 1):

*If you want to display 5.00 as 5 & 5.10 as 5.1 then use:*

```
 DecimalFormat formater = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
```

If you want to display  5.00 as 5.00 & 5.10 as 5.10 then use:

```
DecimalFormat formater = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        double rews = 100.89478;
        String ada = new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(rews);
        System.out.println(ada);
```

> Output

```
100.89
```

Here `.##` so it will give 2 decimal points. if you want to add 3 means use `.###`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct, However please have a look here,

```
  System.out.printf("Floating point number with 2 decimal digits: %.2f\n",1.21312939123); 
  System.out.printf("Floating point number with 3 decimal digits: %.3f\n",1.21312939123);
  System.out.printf("Floating point number with 8 decimal digits: %.8f\n",1.21312939123);
  System.out.printf("String: %s, integer: %d, float: %.6f", "Hello World",89,9.231435);
```

Output:

```
Floating point number with 2 decimal digits: 1.21
Floating point number with 3 decimal digits: 1.213
Floating point number with 8 decimal digits: 1.21312939
String: Hello World, integer: 89, float: 9.231435
```